# How to smoothly transition my iPhone back to iOS 11 non-beta?

Tags: iphone, ios, beta

I signed up and have been using iOS 11 Beta due to ability to record screen video.

But now that iOS 11 is officially released, I am still getting the newest Beta of iOS 11. How do I smoothly transition back to using iOS 11 non-beta?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's [pretty easy](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll#ios).

go to Settings > General > Profiles and tap the iOS Beta Software Profile that appears. Then just delete it. When the next non-beta update is released you can update to it then, or you can back up the phone and restore the current version.

Comment: I guess "hopefully", if my version is 11.2.5 Beta and the next official release is 11.2.0 or 11.2.4, then it won't cause anomalies because it is going backward.  If the next official release is 11.2.5 I suppose it should be ok. Actually, when I check my iPhone, it has 11.2.5 (15D60), which is the same as what Wikipedia lists as the official release (so beta was the same as official release this time?)